# AsyncTask missing return statement

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Android Studio is insisting that I am missing a return value in `doInBackground`, even though it seems to be declared as `Void`. Am I overlooking something?

```
AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void> initiateConnection = new AsyncTask<WebSocketClient, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(WebSocketClient ... clients) {
            clients[0].connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(st, "Socket connected.");
        }
    };
    initiateConnection.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Void` (uppercase `V`) is not `void` (lowercase `v`). With `void`, you can just "fall off the bottom of the method". With `Void`, you need to explicitly return something, typically `null`.

Comment: This causes the entire `AsyncTask` to return the following error: incompatible types
required: AsyncTask<Boolean,Void,Void>
found:    <anonymous AsyncTask<WebSocketClient,Void,Void>>

Comment: @erythraios: That is because your variable data type (`AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void>`) does not match the data type of the object that you are creating (`AsyncTask<WebSocketClient, Void, Void>`). They need to match.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return null

```
protected Void doInBackground(WebSocketClient ... clients) {
    clients[0].connect();

    return null;
}
```